# Semantic video search

Tags: video-processing, openai-api, semantic-search, openai-clip

I am attempting to extend OpenAI's CLIP functionality to semantic video search. Essentially, my objective is to input a text query and get relevant video segments/clips that match the semantic content of the text query. Here's what I've thought so far:

1. Extract frames from the video at regular intervals.
2. Use CLIP to create embeddings of these frames and the text query.
3. Compare the text query embeddings with the video frame embeddings to find matches.

However, this approach seems quite naive, and I feel it might not effectively capture the context in the videos due to the temporal information being lost.

Can anyone share advice on improving this approach? Is there a more efficient or effective way to implement semantic video search with OpenAI's CLIP? Also, I'm wondering about any preprocessing steps, possible optimization strategies, or libraries that could be beneficial for this task.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified step-by-step:

1. **Chunk the Video into 1-second Intervals**

   To divide the video into 1-second chunks, you would typically use a library like `moviepy` or `opencv`.

   ```py
   import cv2

   video = cv2.VideoCapture('your_video.mp4')

   fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
   frames = []

   while(video.isOpened()):
       ret, frame = video.read()
       if ret:
           frames.append(frame)
       else:
           break

   video.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()

   # Now chunk into 1-second intervals
   chunks = [frames[i:i+int(fps)] for i in range(0, len(frames), int(fps))]
   ```
2. **Generating the Embeddings**

   For each 1-second chunk, a series of images are generated, and the embeddings are calculated using the OpenAI CLIP model.

   ```py
   import torch
   import clip

   model, preprocess = clip.load('ViT-B/32')

   for chunk in chunks:
       # For each frame in the chunk, preprocess and convert to tensor
       images = [torch.unsqueeze(preprocess(frame), 0) for frame in chunk]

       # Stack all tensors together
       images_input = torch.cat(images, 0)

       # Generate the embedding
       with torch.no_grad():
           image_features = model.encode_image(images_input)
   ```
3. **Performing the Search**

   You can use cosine similarity:

```
    # Calculate cosine similarity between the corpus of vectors and the query vector
    scores = util.cos_sim(query_vector, corpus_vector)[0].cpu().tolist()
    
    # Combine docs & scores
    doc_score_pairs = list(zip(docs, scores))
    
    # Sort by decreasing score
    doc_score_pairs = sorted(doc_score_pairs, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    
    # Output passages & scores
    for doc, score in doc_score_pairs:
        print(score, doc)
```

The challenge with this approach however is treating 1 second intervals as a series of frames does not capture the context of the video. They should be treated as moving images.

Mixpeek offers a managed search API that does this:

`GET: https://api.mixpeek.com/v1/search?q=people+experiencing+joy`

Response:

```
[
  {
    "content_id": "6452f04d4c0c0888bdc6b97c",
    "metadata": {
      "file_ext": "mp4",
      "file_id": "ebc289d7-44e1-4672-bf3c-ccfa490b7k2d",
      "file_url": "https://mixpeek.s3.amazonaws.com/<user>/<file>.mp4",
      "filename": "CR-9146f0.mp4",
    },
    "score": 0.636489987373352,
    "timestamps": [
      2.5035398230088495,
      1.2517699115044247,
      3.755309734513274
    ]
  }
]
```

Further reading and demo: https://learn.mixpeek.com/what-is-semantic-video-search/